# Using t-test to get pValue for observed state in two vectors

Tags: r, p-value

I am planning to use this on network data.

My network has two kinds of edges. 
I have written a function which returns the indegree for these two edge types separately for you to see what it looks like:

```
    Node    G_obs   R_obs
1   N1      3       2
2   N2      1       0
3   N3      9       0
4   N4      1       4
5   N5      1       0
...
```

and I wrote another function which samples the network edges. Here is what it looks like after this:

```
    Node    G_obs   R_obs
1   N1      4       1
2   N2      1       0
3   N3      3       6
4   N4      3       2
5   N5      1       0
...
```

Note that the G_obs+R_obs, aka the indegree of the node stays the same.

I'd like to know the pValue for each node to have the originally observed indegree-split between G_obs and R_obs.

**EDIT:**
Sorry - this seemed to be a little too unclear.
I don't want the *row-wise* probability of the observed distribution.
I want the probability of the observed *G_obs, R_obs split* for each node, where sample(G_obs) + sample(R_obs) still have the same sum for node as before.
I should consult an English native speaker for better wording next time.. Hope I described the problem more clearly now :(

**EDIT 2**

observation:

```
    Node    G_obs   R_obs
1   N1      3       2
2   N2      1       0
3   N3      9       0
4   N4      1       4
5   N5      1       0
```

as you can see, N1 has 5 in-edges. 3 of them are green (G_obs), 2 of them are red (R_obs)

for the 5 Nodes shown, we have 15 green edges in total and 6 red edges in total.
Now we 'sample' all green and all red edges, aka re-distribute them in their assigned column - but at the same time, N1 still has 5 edges. (See example sampling above, where

```
    Node    G_obs   R_obs
1   N1      4       1
...
```

I already have a function which provides the 'sampling' correctly (placeholder for this: `mySample(graph)` ) and need a function which takes mySample, uses it e.g. 1000 times, and calculates how likely the orginal oberservation was for each node.

Any help appreciated 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are after a binomial probability (the probability that randomly dividing the edges between the two types will yield the same distribution as originally observed).

You can compute these probabilities using the `dbinom()` function:

```
transform(
  df,
  prob_same = dbinom(G_obs, G_obs + R_obs, prob = .5)
)
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "
   Node    G_obs   R_obs
N1      3       2
N2      1       0
N3      9       0
N4      1       4
N5      1       0
  ",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and short way to do it! What does `prob = .5` do? Could you explain the value?

Comment: `prob = .5` just indicates that, when randomly placing edges between G_obs and R_obs, the probability that a given edge is G_obs is 0.5.

Comment: Is it correct that this method calculates prob_same between all possible distributions of each row by looking at this certain row only or is it taking all other edges into account too? (I need the latter)

Comment: Your original question asked for the Pvalue (which I read as 'probability') of each node. The solution above gives one probability for each node. Are you looking for a single probability that all nodes have same distribution?

Comment: You interpreted it correctly, but I wondered if your answer does the calculation row-wise or like an applied t.test where each row gets a pValue but it's still calculated by use of whole column. It's hard to get - sorry for that . At times like this I miss pm for follow up questions

Comment: Can you update your question to include desired output?